# How to create Hash Map with a Json which as an array in it

Tags: rest, api, automation, hashmap, rest-assured

Like in below Json, i want create an HashMap-

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "lname": "Smith",
    "age": "25",
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
        "city": "New York"

    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "212 555-1234"
        },
        {
            "type": "fax",
            "number": "646 555-4567" 
        }
    ] 
}
```

I have tried below code, but i am not sure how to add "PhoneNumber" as it's having Array in it.Kindly help me-

```
HashMap<String,Object> jsonAsMap=new HashMap<String,Object>();
jsonAsMap.put("name", "Rajesh");
jsonAsMap.put("lname", "Singh");
jsonAsMap.put("age", "45");

HashMap<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>();

map.put("streetAddress", "123 Civil lines");
map.put("city", "Delhi");
jsonAsMap.put("address", "map");
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use `JSONObject` than HashMap, I've answered to your question anyway

Comment: Thanks @WilfredClement. We can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to create a HashMap with Arrays as list,

```
Arrays.asList(new HashMap<String, Object>()
```

Complete code below :

```
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("name", "John");
    map.put("lname", "Smith");
    map.put("age", "25");

    HashMap<String,Object> address=new HashMap<>();

    address.put("streetAddress", "123 Civil lines");
    address.put("city", "Delhi");
    map.put("address", address);

    map.put("phoneNumbers", Arrays.asList(new HashMap<String, Object>() {
        {
            put("type", "home");
            put("number", "212 555-1234");
        }},new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("type", "fax");
            put("number", "646 555-4567");
        }}
        ));

    String json = new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(map);

    System.out.println(json)
```

This will generate the output in json but not in the same order as the json you have posted, if you need the same order then use `LinkedHashMap`